# Python SMTP not working even with "correct" settings (logs in doesnt send)

Tags: python, flask, smtp, smtplib, zoho

I'm trying to send an OTP via email (which I save in a DB as well) and even though I believe my config is right because it logs in, it doesn't send messages (it did the first 2 times and then stopped):

```
 message = """Subject: Your OTP
    Hi, your your otp is {otp}"""
    from_address = "REDACTED"
    password = "REDACTED"
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    print('xyz')
    msg = message.format(otp=otp)
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host="smtppro.zoho.eu", port = 465, context=context) as server:
        print('xyz')
        server.login(from_address, password)
        print('logs')
        server.ehlo('127.0.0.1') ## i tried the ehlo() as well and without it all together
        print(email) ## prints this and then gets stuck
        server.sendmail(
            from_address,
            email,
            msg
        )
        print('sent')
        server.quit() ##i may had forgotten to have that the first 2 times
        print('quit')
    return "OTP sent to your email"
```

As you can see in the code block I had forgotten the `quit()` thing the first 2 times and I thought maybe there is something wrong with the session. I restarted the server 2 times in hopes to reset the connection.

Mind the comments I have made in the code block.

For the password I used my account password as well as an APP password (just for use in an app), and as I said there wasnt a problem with the log in.

After sometime (2-3 minutes) I get this in my terminal:

```
 File "/home/blank/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/blank/scripts/test/emails.py", line 56, in sendmail
    server.sendmail(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/smtplib.py", line 902, in sendmail
    (code, resp) = self.data(msg)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/smtplib.py", line 580, in data
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/smtplib.py", line 405, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Comment: Have you tried generating [Application Specific Password](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/two-factor-authentication.html#alink7) if you have enabled TFA?

Comment: @ShriHariL Yes thats what i am using, App specific password.. i will try again but its very weird that i was able to send 3 emails. 
Having my own email server is something that will happen later, i just need to test for dev purposes for now

Comment: You need an `f"""..."""` stringt for the variable to be interpolated, and an empty line between the headers and the body. But like everyone has been saying, use the `email` library to create a valid message for SMTP, especially if you are not an expert on the protocol and all its weird corner cases.

Comment: Also, the argument to `ehlo` should be the sending system's identity, not some random string you found in Google.

Comment: You don't need the `quit` if you use a `with` context manager.

Answer (score 0):

3 things to try:

1. Replace `server.ehlo('127.0.0.1')` by `server.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()`
2. Add `server.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()` just after the `with` line (before the `server.login` line) (since its "if needed" you can add it at every function call of your SMTP object)
3. Try to use the Python library `email.message` to generate an `email.message.EmailMessage` object you can pass to `smtplib.SMTP_SSL` (or to every SMTP object from `smtplib`) to the function `server.send_message` instead of manually make the string containing the raw message and passing it to `server.sendmail`.
   Also, try to avoid using Python 3.9 as I got same error on that version, and changing to Python 3.11 fixed the problem (combined with these 3 other tips).